# Problem with dropdown menu black dashboard pro

Tags: bootstrap-4

I made a purchase of the black dashboard pro template and I have a very peculiar little problem. We have 4 computers here in the office and we are using this template in one of the projects, of these 4 computers 3 the template is not working even with the **>>> default (black dashboard pro) template provided by the bootstrap library <<**. On these three computers the dropdown menu opens but when you click it again it doesn't close, has anyone had similar problem or know what may be influencing this kind of thing?

What is the point of working on only one while the 4 computers are exactly the same in hardware and software, using the same database?

Comment: see in the console, did you get any error from it?

Comment: No, no error is shown on console.

Comment: This is using the default template, when you click on the dashboard there it does not come back and on my co-worker's computer it works normally.

https://imgur.com/a/IEFUZGq